# Action bar not able to show provide icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

[image]

I want to make action bar like the image given above..  .

So is it possible to add the image directly or some other way to do this,As i tried to do so but image get padded in action bar..
Kindly help on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try the http://actionbarsherlock.com/ and download the zip library extarct it and add the lib file to your project and then try write the Style and try to apply the style to the ActionbarSherlock using following code
`ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_layout);`